# Jenkins SCM polling doesn't accept build parameter default

Tags: svn, jenkins

- Jenkins v1.652
- Subversion plug-in v2.5.7

I've set up a build with a "List Subversion tags" parameter. The parameter's name is `SVN_PATH` with a repository URL of, say, `svn://serv/proj`. The "default value" is `trunk` and the help bubbles suggest that this default value will be used by SCM polling (for which parameters cannot be specified).

[image: Screenshot of build parameter section]

Under Source Code Management, I'm using the "Subversion" option with repository URL of `svn://serv/proj/$SVN_PATH` (as suggested in the same help bubbles).

[image: Screenshot of SCM section]

The manually-started parameterised builds work fine.

However, SCM polling still fails; the Subversion Polling Log says

> Started on 08-Mar-2016 12:36:00
>   Location 'svn://serv/proj/$SVN_PATH' does not exist
>   One or more repository locations do not exist anymore for hudson.model.FreeStyleProject@4789095b[jobName], project will be disabled.
>   The project has been disabled
>   Done. Took 16 ms
>   No changes

and the job is automatically disabled.

Since the documentation suggests the default of `trunk` should be interpolated into the repository URL for SCM polling purposes, I'm at a loss as to how to get this working.

Is this a known issue? Do I need to use a different plug-in, or configure something differently?

Comment: My back-up plan is to use post-commit hooks instead, but I'd like to keep all the config within Jenkins if possible.

Comment: According to the subversion plugin changelog (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin), this problem should be fixed in the version 2.5.4 :(

Comment: @BrunoLavit: Indeed :( Perhaps I'm configuring it wrong?

Comment: Did you try to add (or remove) the accolades? You can also try to change the variable name (just to test). Otherwise, your configuration looks good... :(

Comment: @BrunoLavit: Hmm what are accolades please?

Comment: {} (sorry I'm French :D)

Comment: @BrunoLavit: Ah. Braces! Yeah same with or without them :(

Comment: What happens if you set your repository url to point at `svn://serv/proj/trunk` and leave the default value blank?

Comment: @Tuffwer: Then I'm not using parameterised builds any more (and, for the sake of completion, the job works)

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet Yeah, I should have realized the loss of parameterized builds.  I know it would be a pain (because what else are defaults for?), but does it still fail if you pass the parameter explicitly as trunk instead of letting the starting job just let this job fall through on the default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that, for precisely two out of nine jobs, SCM polling was apparently working.

After some time I discovered that these are the only two jobs on which I have ever performed a manual build on a tag, and that the SCM polling was actually polling those tags, not trunk.

The other seven were erroring out presumably because no "historically built tag" exists yet.

**Consequently I believe this is [JENKINS-32582](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32582).**